# HttpContext.Current.Session is null requesting images. Why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building a ASP MVC application.

When I request a route to a controller, for example:

```
http://myserver/sales/id/5
```

the session object `HttpContext.Current.Session` is working perfectly.

However, when I'm requesting an image or a script, for example:

```
http://myserver/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js
```

the session object `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null`

How I can distinguish this situation from other when there is no "real" session (for example first login)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you need a session for retrieving a static file?

Unless you are using a dynamic handler, there is absolutely no need for session to retrieve such content.

My point is that session does not serve any useful purpose for retrieving static content, so it is not available.

Answer (score 2):

@Oded is right, this is an optimization in asp.net. If you need the session to be available, then you will need the request to go to a handler that has indicated it needs the session. If you are writing your own handler, then it simply needs to implement the marker interface [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx).

This optimization isn't just for the current request, but any parallel requests that you are making as multiple requests that use the same session are handled in a serial fashion. Read my [blog post](http://coderelease.blogspot.com/2011/03/iis-only-serves-one-request-per-session.html) for more info on this.

Comment: I get a 404 on your blog post.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the link to the new location of my blog.