# Why "File does not exist." exception in Application_Error does not have access to Session Data?

Tags: asp.net, session, exception, application-error

HttpContext.Current.Session object is null when application throws "File does not exist." exception in Application_Error event.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex.Message == "File does not exist." && HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
    {
        if (((System.Web.HttpException)(ex)).GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            LogtheException(Session["uname"].ToString());// Throwing the Exception Here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LogtheException(Session["uname"].ToString());
        Server.Transfer(UrlMaker.ToError(ex.Message.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Throwing Exception

```
Session state is not available in this context.
```

Why HttpContext.Current.Session object is null when if any css/image file path is not correct. Instead it should throw FileNotFoundException and also have access to Session Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977787/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-requesting-images-why)
Css and image requests normally don't need to access the session, therefor asp does not load the session into memory and you don't have access to it on error.